# How can l get my old what's up in my phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have my whatsup accont in my old phone.recently I purchesed a new phone.and I opened my account in new phone.aftet five days my new phone got a problem my phone completelyswitced off and not turnrd on when I went to service center they told me that your phone has mother board problem it will take to clear minimum 45 days.now how can I activate my account in my old phone.

Comment: On ypur old phone, download a newer version of WhatsApp and put your phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Using "Restore" option you can get back your old data of whatsapp. But this will only work when you back up your data or save the directory "whatsapp" which is located in your sdcard. or if you attach your data to mail